# MySQL: Join a table to itself

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table of preferences, called "txp_prefs". I would like to return multiple preferences into a single row; the reason I prefer this to a simple concatenation is that I'm using a plugin in textpattern which can process the single row.

Here is the testing data I have:

```
------------------------------------------------
|Id | event   | name             |value        |
------------------------------------------------
| 1 | season  | season_start     | 12/10/2011  |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2 | season  | season_end       | 29/10/2011  |
------------------------------------------------
| 3 | season  | season_countdown | 7           |
------------------------------------------------
| 4 | another | test1            | result1     |
------------------------------------------------
| 3 |         | test2            | result2     |
------------------------------------------------
```

The final result I would like to get is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|event    | season_start | season_end | season_countdown |
----------------------------------------------------------
|season   | 12/10/2011   | 29/10/2011 | 7                |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I can (obviously) create the separate queries to get each result independently; for example

```
SELECT t1.event, t1.val AS season_start FROM txp_prefs t1 WHERE t1.event="season" AND t1.name="season_start" (to get the season_start)
SELECT t2.event, t2.val AS season_end FROM txp_prefs t2 WHERE t2.event="season" AND t2.name="season_end" (to get the season_end)
```

But I get errors when I try to join the two together, eg like this:

```
SELECT t1.event, t1.val AS season_start FROM txp_prefs t1 WHERE t1.event="season" AND t1.name="season_start"
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT t2.event, t2.val AS season_end FROM txp_prefs t2 WHERE t2.event="season" AND t2.name="season_end") t3
ON t1.event=t3.event
```

The error messages says it is something to do with the join (which I guessed anyway - the two individual queries work.

Any ideas? I have recently figured through joining different tables together, so I assume it is possible to join a table to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the structure given you can use

```
SELECT 
     MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'season_start' THEN value END) AS season_start,
     MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'season_end' THEN value END) AS season_end,
     MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'season_countdown' THEN value END) AS season_countdown
FROM txp_prefs
WHERE event='season'
```

Comment: I tried this (adding FROM txp_prefs to the end) and I get a new (but different error).

Comment: Where did you add the `FROM txp_prefs`? Needs to be before the `WHERE`. If it *is* before the `WHERE` please reveal the new but different error message!

Comment: Sorry, just realised it was already there. This works - error message was due to change in the field name (my fault for the wrong description). Thanks everyone - brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

select you are looking for is:

```
SELECT distinct
          t0.event, 
          t1.val AS season_start , 
          t2.val as seasson_end, 
          t3.val as season_countdown
    FROM 
       txp_prefs t0 
          left outer join
       txp_prefs t1 
          on ( t1.event=t0.event AND t1.name="season_start" )
          left outer join
       txp_prefs t2
          on ( t2.event=t0.event AND t2.name="season_end" )
          left outer join
       txp_prefs t3
          on ( t3.event=t0.event AND t3.name="season_countdown" )
    WHERE 
       t0.event="season"
```

(the standard way to get only one row is 'distintc' reserved word. Another solution is append 'LIMIT 1' to query, but this is MySQL dependant)

are you sure that your database is right normalized?

see you.

Comment: That worked to a point, but it returns three identical rows with the required data. It would be better to just get a single row from the point of view of processing the results.

Comment: Solved on answer. But ... are you sure that your database is right normalized?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by pivoiting. Asper my past project I demostrate you in following query hope will be useful to you.

My table transaction is having following fields

```
 NAME VARCHAR2(10)
 branch_code NUMBER(4)
 Ruppes NUMBER(4)


SQL> select * from transaction;

NAME branch_code Ruppes
---------- ---------- ----------
Hemang 2602 1000
Hemang 2603 2000
Hemang 2400 3000
Yash 2602 1500
Yash 2603 1200
Yash 2400 1340
Krupesh 2602 1250
Krupesh 2603 2323
Krupesh 2400 8700
```

9 rows selected.

Now pivoting.

```
SQL> select branch_code, 
  2 max( decode( name, 'Hemang', Ruppes, null ) ) "Hemang",
  3 max( decode( name, 'Yash', Ruppes, null ) ) "Yash",
  4 max( decode( name, 'Krupesh', Ruppes, null ) ) "Krupesh"
  5 from
  6 (
  7 select name, branch_code, Ruppes
  8 from transaction
  9 )
 10 group by branch_code ;

      branch_code Hemang Yash Krupesh
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      2602 1000 1500 1250
      2603 2000 1200 2323
      2400 3000 1340 8700
```

Comment: OK, thanks I'll try that out as well, but the earlier answer from Martin Smith has done the trick and I still want to figure out exactly what it is doing so I can learn from this as well.

Comment: ok then I hope you will mark this as an answer. so that others can also have look on this.